# Symfony2 how to make Ajax Request with doctrine update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am developing a interface for edit page of my website. CKeditor is used. I want use Ajax method to save the modification. My text is stock in DB. I use Doctrine to access to him.

script jQuery

```
$(".loading").hide();

$('[name="contentsForm"]').submit(function() {
    $('[name="contentsForm"]').hide();
    $("#contents .loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ path('AdminAjaxEditText', {'page' : 'index', 'description' : 'contents'})}}",
        data: "{'data': '" + $('#contentsForm_data').val() + "'}",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('[name="contentsForm_data"]').html(data);
            CKupdate();
            $('[name="contentsForm"]').show();
            $("#contents .loading").hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Controller php

```
public function ajaxEditAction($page, $description, Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $text = $em->getRepository("FDMWebsiteBundle:Text")->find(array("page" => $page, "description" => $description));
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed($description."Form", new TextType(), $text);

    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render("Bundle:Admin:textForm.html.twig", array(
        "form" => $form->createView()
        ));
}
```

Template twig

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': ''}, {'method': 'POST'}) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form.data, { 'attr': {'class': 'ckeditor'} }) }}
<input type="submit" class="saveTextBtn btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Enregistrer"/>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

My problem is when is click on save the Ajax run but nothing is saved in my DB ?

What wrong I have done ?

I don't understand why my code is not flush but is displayed in textarea after the Ajax request.

Sorry for my English, I am learning it...

Comment: Hi, you should use `findBy` instead of just `find` to get the database entry. The `find`-method is to be used with the id of the entry. Use `findBy` or `findOneBy` with an array of where statements. Then you should receive the right entry and can update it.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

Comment: I use find because my entity have composite primary key

Comment: You $form variable is set before the forms input is valided (and flushed). Therefore the response will contain still the old, just from the database loaded values. Might to reload the data after flushing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my problem**s**

First I need to set the charset to utf-8 and get data form CKEditor not form the textarea

```
scriptCharset: "utf-8",
data: "data=" + CKEDITOR.instances['contentsForm_data'].getData()
```

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData

Second : My ajax controller need to use getter's request. The handleRequest method of form isn't working, I don't knonw why. If someone can give me a explain I am looking for it.

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $data = $request->request->get('data');
    $text->setData($data);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Tutorial and some post use this solution but I don't understand why handlerResquest fail ?

Third: I need to configure CKEDITOR to don't use entities

```
CKEDITOR.config.entities = false;
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities